# Check whether two points in time are in different adjacent days

Tags: java, android, date

How can I determine if there is one midnight between two points in time. That is, that the two points are in different adjacent days??

I would be easy to store UNIX timestamp and check 24h difference but what I need is when checking between 2 timestamps for example Monday at 23:00h and Tuesday at 02:00h the difference has to be one day, same as between Monday 10:00h and Tuesday 19:00h

Comment: It is completely unclear to me what you are asking. Are you asking "how can I tell if Monday at 23:00h and Tuesday at 02:00h are exactly one day apart"? Are you asking "how can I determine what is exactly one day in the future from Monday at 23:00h"? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: I understand: He wants to know wheter there was a midnight inbetween two dates. (As shown on each flight ticket with "+1" =next day

Comment: It's exactly what I mean, "how can I tell if Monday at 23:00h and Tuesday at 02:00h are exactly one day apart" same as Tuesday at 21:00h

Comment: Use java GregorianCalendar

Comment: @ics "one day apart" is not exact. read my comment; is that what you want to kbnow? Midnight transition inbetween?

Comment: @AlexWien now you brought that up,  I think it's the same principle,  yes

Comment: @hd1 done! GregorianCalendar worked just fine without extra libs, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally opted for @AlexWien's answer, which for some reason has been deleted.

@hd1 joda is nice but this is for an android project and the library is too heavy and I would use it only here.

That's why I have opted for the GregorianCalendar approach:

```
public static int daysApart(long first, long second){
    GregorianCalendar gc=new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

    gc.setTimeInMillis(first);
    int day1=gc.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

    gc.setTimeInMillis(second);
    int day2=gc.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

    return day2-day1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I always use [joda](http://joda-time.sf.net) for date/time manipulation in Java. Using joda, your code is:

```
if (Days.daysBetween(new DateTime(myFirstJavaUtilDateOrMiliseconds), new DateTime(mySecondJavaUtilDateOrMiliseconds)).getDays()) == 1) { // 1 day difference
} else { // not so much
}
```

Of course, if you're using the JDK date classes and can't use Joda, accept a different answer.

Comment: There is more simple than that actually: `first.minusDays(1).equals(second)` ;)

Comment: You would still need to construct your DateTime objects using the constructor, as DateTime doesn't inherit from it.